# jquery merge elements

Tags: jquery

I'm in the process of refactoring one of my jquery ui widgets.
In order to get a cleaner code I do the base html stuff with templating.
The base container for the widget is a div. The widget user might design it like this:

```
 <div id="mywidget" class="status" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 250px;"></div>
```

Now, in the widget source I have the base html elements in a string:

```
 '<div class="ui-grouping ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">' +
 '<span class="ui-grouping-detail"><img src="....
```

When the user creates the widget with $('#mywidget').abcd(); I do NOT want to append the html-string to the base div, but I want to merge the string into the base div, so that the end result looks like:

```
 <div id="mywidget" class="status ui-grouping ui-widget ui-widget-contet ui-corner-all" 
   style="margin-top: 10px; width: 250px;">
 <span class="ui-grouping-detail"><img src=" ...
```

I did not find a function $('#mywidget').mergeWith("....").
What would be a good solution for that?
Thanks alot
Wolfgang

Update:
Thank you, Didier Ghys, for your answer.
But I want to get away from the solution you proposed. Your solution is the standard way things are done in jquery ui widgets.
You have to search long to find the usage of templating in jquery widgets (in order to get the separation of markup and javascript and therefore to get a cleaner/clearer code).
As I understand it, in dojo widgets it is far more common to use templating in widgets. 
So, once again, thank you Didier Ghys, but I search for another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DaKeg/

```
var str = '<div class="ui-grouping ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">' +
 '<span class="ui-grouping-detail">dskfjsdmf</span></div>';

$("#mywidget").addClass(getFirstClass(str));
$("#mywidget").append(getElementInside(str));

function getFirstClass(_str){
    return $(_str).closest('div').attr('class');
}
function getElementInside(_str){
    return $(_str).closest('div').children();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, mgraph, for your answer, interesting approach. I will take it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not store the base elements as a string and just add the classes and such programatically to the markup provided by the user of the plugin:

```
$('<div id="mywidget" class="status" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 250px;"></div>')
    .addClass('ui-grouping ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all')
    .append('<span class="ui-grouping-detail">')
```

Is that what you're after ?